# Under which circumstances SNMP interface index(ifIndex) in Cisco IOS changes?

Tags: snmp

In Cisco IOS each interface has unique `ifIndex` which is an integer >0(AFAIK usually starts from 1). If [snmp-server ifindex persist](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/28420-ifIndex-Persistence.html) is not used, then it is possible that `ifIndexes` are mapped differently than before. Under which circumstances SNMP `ifIndex` in Cisco IOS might change? I know that reload is one possible reason. Are there any other reasons which might cause SNMP `ifIndex` to change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Adding or removing physical interfaces
- Adding or removing logical interfaces (vlan, dialer, tunnel, etc.)

In short, anything that changes the number (or order) of IDB entries. The index starts at one and always increments. The enumeration process starts fresh when the system boots. (if persistence isn't enabled, or someone deletes the database -- it's a file in nvram.)

Comment: I moved around and removed `WS-X4306-GB` and `WS-X4448-GB-RJ45` modules in `WS-C4506` chassis and `ifIndex` values according to `sh snmp mib ifmib ifindex` assigned to card were not changed once they were initially(for example when module was first time inserted) assigned. Same seems to be true for tunnel or dot1q or VLAN interfaces. So in short, interface will get a new SNMP `ifIndex` only in case of router reload?

Comment: Yes, OIR will retain the ifIndex as long as the router isn't reloaded. This so a faulty module can be replaced.